# When Azure Active Directory Oauth2 V2.0 endpoint will provide access_code that will support Azure Resource Manager APIs?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Base on this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-limitations/

the new V2.0 endpoint will not provide access_code that will support ARM APIs, any suggestion on when this will be support?

Thanks!

Comment: ehm, don't you feel like this is an off-topic question for SO? It's not about any specific problem one can help solve with some code (of reasonable size) or suggestion about how to code..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, no timeline as of yet.